# Testing firebase cloud functions - validate database changes

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions

Based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) for unit testing Cloud Functions, I understand how I could effectively test rather simple Cloud Functions by asserting a response to be what I would expect it. However, I have a few somewhat complex Cloud Functions, where on change of one type of data in my database, a number of private methods retrieve a few other types of data, make calculations on those, I then put a number of database update calls into an array of promises and call `Promise.all(my_array)` on it to complete my Cloud Function execution.

This results in the response being an array of variable length and composition, which is very difficult to validate.

Instead, I would prefer to be able to test Cloud Functions in a sequence something like below:

- Set an initial database
- Trigger a Could Function
- Check the updated database if all is as I expect

Is it possible to do something like this with the `firebase-functions-test` library? How do I do it? I understand the above scenario is more of an integration test, still I'd like to know if said library would be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing should all be possible with (and is a better fit for) the Firebase emulator suite, which is:

> The Firebase Local Emulator Suite consists of individual service emulators built to accurately mimic the behavior of Firebase services. This means you can connect your app directly to these emulators to perform integration testing or QA without touching production data.
>
> For example, you could connect your app to the Firestore emulator to safely read and write documents in testing. These writes may trigger functions in the Cloud Functions emulator. However your app will still continue to communicate with production Firebase services when emulators are not available or configured.

For more on this, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite).